# How to disassemble the running linux kernel?

Tags: linux, security, linux-kernel

Looking for a way to disassemble the running kernel. Can I do it through /dev/kmem? I am running linux 2.6.32. Or can I use a kernel module to run through the kernel. I am beginner to this. Please help.

All I want to do is check the kernel image for some malicious module, by looking at the whether some specific instruction occured or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [Linux Kernel Debugger](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-kdbug/).

**Update**

As I said, try the [Linux Kernel Debugger](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-kdbug/).  Look in the linked article, about halfway down the page, where it says:

> To **disassemble instructions** starting
>   from the routine `schedule`. The number
>   of lines displayed depends on the
>   environment variable `IDCOUNT`:

```
[0]kdb> id schedule
```

Comment: I am looking for a way to disassemble the running kernel image

Comment: Foound that `GDB` also could do it. http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/detecting-rootkits-and-kernel-level-compromises-linux