# Linux, how to disassemble syscalls

Tags: linux, unix, assembly, system-calls, strace

I'm running `strace ls` to print out the system calls used by `ls` command.

[image]

Now, let's say I want to disassembly the highlighted commands to view their machine instructions. How to do that?

Comment: Please state the output and the errors. The text on the picture cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disassemble the running linux kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835961/how-to-disassemble-the-running-linux-kernel)

Comment: @RobinGreen - It is what he ultimately what he wants to do, but not what he actually asked.

Comment: I know that system calls are implemented by stubs in glibc which call the real system calls. But that's a technicality. I think this question really is a duplicate of that question, for all intents and purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The above cannot be "disassembled" to machine instructions.  What strace is showing you is a listing of syscalls that have been made with a summary of their arguments helpfully pretty-printed.

It is certainly not possible to get a listing of the machine instructions that made those calls from the output.  Or even a usable sequence of instructions that could reproduce those calls without the stuff in between<sup>1</sup>.

If you really want to see the instructions that were executed, you need to use a debugger, not `strace`.

---

<sup>1 - Because the `strace` output only outputs a *summary* of the arguments.  Notice the ellipsis?</sup>

Comment: But if I want to *statically* inspect the machine code implementation of those syscalls, where are they located and how would I disassemble them?

Comment: Ummm .... the syscalls implementations are in the kernel source code.  Why would you want to disassemble them if you can read the source code?   (And besides, the `strace` output doesn't record anything for you to disassemble.)

Comment: I would like to disassemble them for educational purposes. I don't want to disassemble the syscall execution during `strace`, but the syscall as it is.

Comment: Then disassemble the kernel (have fun!)